# Clojure binding : Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var

Tags: clojure, binding

I'm starting with Clojure and trying to bind (or true) to be (true). I get the following error:

CompilerException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn, compiling:(myproject\core.clj:8:26)

Here's the code:

```
(declare ^:dynamic or)
(binding [or true] (true))
```

If I just do

```
(binding [or true] (true))
```

I get:

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojure.core/or, compiling:(myproject\core.clj:5:30)

Comment: Why `true` is in parentheses? It is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true` is not a function. It shouldn't be in parenthesis.

`(declare ^:dynamic or)
(binding [or true] true)`

Note that `or` already refers to `clojure.core/or`. You could name your var `or-` instead.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem. Can you help with this one? I have : (binding [or x false] (x)) and get the error: CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: binding requires an even number of forms in binding vector